# how to get top 1 record from each table based on devicetimestamp order by desc

Tags: sql-server

i want to get latest devicetimestamp data of each table where deviceimei=''.im getting only one table record based on latest time stamp descending order , rest of other tables not getting the latest record based on device time stamp order by descending.

sql

```
 select top 1 * from [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Current_Voltage] as cv
      inner join [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Overview]  as o
       on cv.DeviceImei = o.DeviceImei 
       inner join [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Power]  as p
         on cv.DeviceImei = p.DeviceImei 
        inner join [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[PowerFactor]  as pf
        on cv.DeviceImei = pf.DeviceImei 
         inner join [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Total_Power]  as tp
         on cv.DeviceImei = tp.DeviceImei
      where cv.DeviceImei='8673220311'
      order by cv.DeviceTimeStamp desc
```

Comment: The TOP 1 is applied to the dataset as a whole and after the joins have been applied. You are basically taking the top record based on the ORDER BY clause. Since you are basing the order against one table and not joining any other table on that field then the other tables will be ordered by their Clustered Index, if not a heap.

Comment: can u suggest how to write sql , so that i can get latest record of each table based on deviceimei and order by devicetimestamp desc

Comment: Do you care only about the max timestamps from each of the tables above or do you want the complete record containing the max timestamp from each of the tables?

Comment: i need the latest time stamp records of each table , i mean top 1 record order by timestamp of each table. i want to get the latest value of each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not pretty but here is one solution. In the post above, the joins to the latter tables had no regard to their max or min timestamp, just the device id. Below, the joins have been converted to use subqueries that return the top record from each table ordered by the specified criteria. There will be null fields from tables with no matching records, much like a left join.

```
select top 1 * from [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Current_Voltage] as cv
inner join (
    Select top 1 * from [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Overview] o 
    where cv.DeviceImei='8673220311'
    order by o.DeviceTimeStamp desc
) as o ON 1=1
inner join (
    Select top 1 * from [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Power] p 
    where p.DeviceImei='8673220311'
    order by p.DeviceTimeStamp desc
) as p ON 1=1
inner join (
    Select top 1 * from [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[PowerFactor] pf 
    where pf.DeviceImei='8673220311'
    order by pf.DeviceTimeStamp desc
) as p ON 1=1  
inner join (
    Select top 1 * from [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Total_Power] tp 
    where tp.DeviceImei='8673220311'
    order by tp.DeviceTimeStamp desc
) as tp ON 1=1  
where cv.DeviceImei='8673220311'
order by cv.DeviceTimeStamp desc
```